# Not getting netTcp and wsHttp endpoints when setting "Generate Asynchronous Operations" with service reference in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, wcf, nettcpbinding, wshttpbinding, service-reference

I am creating a wcf service with wsHttp and nettcp service endpoints and then adding a service reference to it in a client app and in advanced setting for that service reference checking "Generate Asynchronous Operations"

I am finding only basicHttp endpoints for the service get added to the app/web config for the client app. Nettcp and wsHttp endpoints to the service do not get added.

How do I correct this so I get netTcp and wshttp endpoints to generate in the app config/ web config for the client app.

Comment: Is this for Silverlight?

Comment: Nope. The client app in this case is a regular .net app. I believe in silverlight the generation of asynchronous operations is automatic.